# Bootstrap progress bar doesn't show progress?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I have a very long loop in JS (2M + iterations).
I would like to show some progress to the user.
For some reason the code hangs, and only shows progress when the loop is done.
What am I doing wrong?

**CAREFUL BROWSER MIGHT GET STUCK, SET MAX ACCORDINGLY**

```js
var MAX = 100000;

function doIt(){        
      alert('start count :'+ MAX);
       for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
          setTimeout(updateBar, 600 , i);
          console.log(i);
       }        
      alert('count ended');
}


function updateBar(idx) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress');
     bar.style.width = Math.floor(100 * idx / MAX) + '%';
}
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button onclick="doIt()">Start counting</button>


<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar" id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: JS is single threaded. While it's doing your calculation, it doesn't do anything else (i.e. update your progress bar). You can either insert timeouts each X iterations, or use a web worker, to do your calculation on another thread.

Comment: (or you can build your calculation so that each iteration of the loop naturally moves the bar)

Comment: Not going to work, unfortunately. The browser won't repaint during those synchronous operations. You couldn't event get a loading GIF to animate, during such calculation

Comment: @Brightstar That only works if you explicitly let your function stop execution and return control to the browser, and schedule more work using something like setTimeout.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Not technically true. I haven't used bootstrap's progress bar, so I'm not sure how hard it would be, but passing a progress bar into your calculation as a parameter and having it increment as part of the calculation is definitely possible. I do similar things all the time in JS. (Granted, you can't do it on a timeout that way, certainly. You COULD set up a variable with the date at start, then compare it at every iteration, updating the progress bar when 500 ms have passed, or w/e.)

Comment: @Brightstar I think maybe we're talking past each other. It's definitely possible to pass a progress bar into a function and increment it as you described. What I meant is that in JS you can't have a classic loop that directly updates a progress bar element based on the progress of that loop - you need to use something asynchronous like a timeout/promise/webworker to prevent the page's main thread from freezing up, so that the browser's event loop has room to breathe and can paint the progress bar to the screen.

Comment: ...which is the crux of the OP's issue, really. OP doesn't use the timeout to cede control to the browser, so the main thread stays in the JS loop, preventing the screen from being redrawn by the browser's event loop. @blex has a great solution, maybe the ideal one, though I might add a simpler answer that shows the old-school way of breaking up loop iterations into batches.

Comment: @Brightstar I just added additional context, including an implementation of the old-school solution, in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59958958/2234742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, using a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers):

[image]

**worker-script.js** (distinct context, distinct file)

```
// When this worker receives a message
self.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceive);

function onMessageReceive(e) {
  // Get the max value
  var max = e.data.value;
  // Run the calculation
  doIt(max);
}

function doIt(max) {
  // Send messages to the parent from time to time
  self.postMessage({ type: "start", value: max });
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if (i % 5000 === 0) { // Every 5000 iterations - tweak this
      self.postMessage({ type: "progress", value: i });
    }
  }
  self.postMessage({ type: "end", value: max });
}
```

**main.js** (in your page)

```
var MAX = 20000000, // 20 millions, no problem
  worker = null;

// If workers are supported, create one by passing it the script url
if (window.Worker) {
  worker = new Worker("worker-script.js");
  document
    .getElementById("start-btn")
    .addEventListener("click", startWorker);
} else {
  alert("Workers are not supported in your browser.");
}

// To start the worker, send it the max value
function startWorker() {
  worker.postMessage({ value: MAX });
}

// When the worker sends a message back
worker.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceive);

function onMessageReceive(e) {
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.type) {
    case "start":
      console.log(`start count: ${data.value}`);
      break;
    case "progress":
      updateBar(data.value);
      break;
    case "end":
      updateBar(data.value);
      console.log(`end count: ${data.value}`);
      break;
  }
}

function updateBar(idx) {
  var bar = document.getElementById("progress");
  bar.style.width = Math.floor((100 * idx) / MAX) + "%";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<button id="start-btn">Start counting</button>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar" id="progress"></div>
</div>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: To be clear, OP's code that actually does stuff should go into the for loop in `worker-script.js`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic issue that occurs as a result of a long-running function that does not halt periodically to pass control back to the browser's Event Loop, where the browser can do other tasks such as painting elements:

> A downside of this model is that if a message takes too long to complete, the web application is unable to process user interactions like click or scroll. The browser mitigates this with the "a script is taking too long to run" dialog. A good practice to follow is to make message processing short and if possible cut down one message into several messages.
>
> [Concurrency model and the event loop - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

When the browser doesn't have any "breathing room" because your JS loop has control, the browser is not able to paint the progress bar.

To fix this, you need to run your loop in chunks, i.e. "cut down one message into several messages", as MDN recommends. To accomplish this you will need to use something asynchronous like a timeout to tell the browser to run the next iteration not "immediately", but "as soon as you're ready". This lets the browser do other important stuff before your function continues (like handle scrolls and clicks, and paint elements such as the progress bar).

---

## Solution

The following solution breaks up the loop by returning control to the browser with `setTimeout(fn, 0)` every `x` iterations.

This is useful if the task you're doing involves the DOM, or for any other reason cannot be run in a web worker. Otherwise [@blex's web worker solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59958147/2234742) is probably better, since any long-running tasks that can be run in background threads should be, for performance reasons.

```js
const MAX = 500000;
let currentIteration = 0;

function doWork(){
       while (currentIteration < MAX) {
        // Do your actual work here, before the increment
        currentIteration++;
        if (currentIteration % 5000 === 0) {
          console.log(currentIteration);
          updateBar(currentIteration);
          setTimeout(doWork, 0);
          return;
        }
       }   
      alert('count ended');
}

function startWork() {
      alert('start count :'+ MAX);
      doWork();
}

function updateBar(idx) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress');
     bar.style.width = Math.floor(100 * idx / MAX) + '%';
}
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button onclick="startWork()">Start counting</button>


<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar" id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've worked hard on this answer. I hope the OP appreciates it.

Comment: I really appreciates it!